# Unexpected "catch Error" Behavior

Tags: solidity, remix, unittesting, remix-tests, try-catch

*IDE: Remix (on Firefox and Brave)

Compiler: v0.8.12*

I am practicing with unit tests on [the Ballot sample contract](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/solidity-by-example.html#voting) from Solidity's documentation, and am having trouble understanding how does `catch Error` behaves.

**Excerpt from contract to be tested** (full contract available in link above):

```solidity
function vote(uint proposal) external {
    Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
    require(sender.weight != 0, "Has no right to vote"); // <- 1st require, requires voter to have voting right allocated
    require(!sender.voted, "Already voted."); // <- 2nd require, requires voter to not have voted already
    sender.voted = true;
    sender.vote = proposal;
    proposals[proposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
}
```

**My test contract:**

```solidity
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
import "remix_tests.sol";
import "remix_accounts.sol";
import "../contracts/Ballot.sol";

contract BallotTest is Ballot {
    
    address acc0; // Contract initiating account
    address acc1; // Testing account
    bytes32[] proposalNames = [bytes32("proposal1")];

    function beforeAll() public {
        acc0 = TestsAccounts.getAccount(0);
        acc1 = TestsAccounts.getAccount(1);
    }

    constructor() Ballot(proposalNames){}
    
    function testGiveRightToVote() public {
        giveRightToVote(acc1); // voters[acc1].weight + 1
    }

    // Unexpected "catch Error" behavior found
    /// #sender: account-1
    function testDoubleVote() public {
        vote(0); // voters[acc1].voted set to true
        try this.vote(0) { // Vote again with voted flag, expect to fail on 2nd require
            Assert.ok(false, "vote should fail");
        } catch Error(string memory reason) {
            Assert.equal(reason, "Already voted.", "failed with unexpected reason"); // <- Test catches "Has no right to vote" instead of "Already voted."
        } catch (bytes memory /*lowLevelData*/) {
            Assert.ok(false, "failed unexpected");
        }
    }
}
```

My problem lies with what I get from `Assert.equal(reason, "Already voted.", "failed with unexpected reason");`

As I am double voting with account-1, I am expecting the `vote` function from the original contract to revert on its second `require` statement and return the error `"Already voted."`.

Yet upon executing my unit test, I am handed with `"Has no right to vote"` from the `vote` function's first `require`, which should supposedly pass without error.

[image: Test double vote fails: Error Message:"failed with unexpected reason"Assertion: Expected value should be equal to Already voted. Received value:Has no right to vote]

Any insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your first vote you vote using `vote(0)`, an internal call which keeps the same transaction context and therefore same msg.sender.

In your second vote you vote using `this.vote(0)`, an external call (to address `this`). This changes the context, and therefore in this call the sender is BallotTest contract and not the original user.

Comment: I see, thanks!
Is there a workaround to carry out a try-catch / a failure test of similar nature with a specific `msg.sender`?